# I can't figure out why a scroll bar appears

Tags: css, scrollbar, responsive-design, horizontal-scrolling

In my first attempt at a responsive web design I have run into a curious problem. When I resize my browser down to 615px width or less, a horizontal scroll bar appears. I'm not sure what element is causing this. I tried putting a border around each element using

```
* {
    border:1px solid #FFF;
}
```

to help me visualize where the edges of the elements were but I don't see any borders extending beyond the window boundaries.

Can someone take a look at my site and give me some insight? http://www.ritualbliss.ca

Thanks!

Edit: So I only get the scroll bar in Firefox. Chrome works fine and the desktop version of Safari but on my iPhone it scrolls horizontally.

Edit: the site is for a legitimate massage business but some may consider the picture NSFW

Comment: Any chance you can edit the question and post a short but working example here? That way when you fix your (linked) site, this question can still be of use to future visitors!

Comment: OK I finally got a chance to see this site and I don't think there's really anything NSFW on screen. The news has worse things. Anyway, I did experience the problem in Firefox and have updated my answer. Can you post your solution? Also, do you have a problem where you can't use CSS3? Using an img tag for your background image seems a little kludgy so if you don't have to conform to older browsers just use the CSS3 stretch option and set your background image that way. Much cleaner and less hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css3 box-sizing:border-box solved this one.

Answer (score 1):

Devin,

Try using a tool like Firebug for Firefox, IE Developer Tools, or the Chrome Developer tools. I'm sure Safari and Opera have similar tools, as well.  These things will give you the ability to highlight and view the various properties of every visible HTML element on the page, including Javascript and CSS information.

One other thing to think about is not using the * selector in your CSS.  I am not sure why you would want to put a border around every single element on your page because to me, that would not look visually appealing.  The border style attribute adds the thickness of the border to whichever dimensions it is applied to.  So, in your case, every element in your page has 2px added to both its height and width, even the "html" element.  This could be why you have the scroll bar but can't tell where the extra pixels are.

Also, do you have any CSS styles that set a width or min-width to 617 pixels?  Or a combination of elements that share the same area and add up to 617 pixels?  Maybe a table with columns that are not shrinkable?

There is a lot to look at and your URL looks like it's probably porno or something so I cannot go there at work and check it out...

Good Luck,

- Matt

***Edit***

I fooled around with firebug for a few minutes and agree with Ruben that handling the overflow would be a good idea.  Although I think the setting should be on the body instead of #content.

Try this:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Like Ruben's answer it is hiding overflow, but you can still get the vertical scrollbar if people REALLY narrow down their browser.

Comment: Not exactly porno but a lubed up body probably isn't safe for work, I'd stay away :)

Comment: thanks Matt. It's not porno it's a legitimate massage therapy business. I only put the border around everything because I couldn't see anything wrong using firebug and thought it might help me visualize where the edges of each element were.

Comment: Borders will not actually do that, because your margins extend past the borders of the element.  So if you have a 1px border and a 10px margin, and a 5px padding your content will be at least 16 px away from the next nearest element or content.  Negative numbers in paddings and margins can also affect the placement of elements on a page in unhappy ways.

Comment: Hey, a year later and a downvote?  Maybe an explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

can you please warn us when it's nsfw :s
use this css:

```
#content { overflow: hidden }
```

not the best solution but you have to use firebug to find out what's sticking out
padding and borders increase the width of your element too

Comment: sorry I didn't realize it might be considered NSFW

Comment: np, but my boss sits next to me and when he sees an oiled body filling my screen he's going too frown :)